# Converting hexadecimal to binary

Tags: c#, binary, hex, decimal

I want to Convert hexadecimal numbers to binary numbers.I search some posts but couldn't find a c# language program.

I used this:

```
value = 0xFFFF;
decimalNum = Convert.ToString(value, 16);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

and then I converted it to binary number. Are there any easier and fast way to do this?

Comment: Easier than a single method call for each base conversion?  I would assume the .NET runtime implementation of ToString() will perform well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var value = 0xFFFF; 
value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString(), 16), 2);
Console.WriteLine(value);
// 1100101010100110101
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan this is what I want!

Comment: Semicolon. five characters to go

Comment: Thanks Millie. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Generate date in hex
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now;
string str = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
string hexDate = dt.Ticks.ToString("X2");

// Convert hex date to date string
UInt64 numericDate = UInt64.Parse(hexDate, 
       System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
long binaryDate = Convert.ToInt64(numericDate);
string strDate = DateTime.FromBinary(binaryDate).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.